# Slow login with Identiy Server 4 using Db storage

Tags: identityserver4

With our current Identity Server 4 implementation using SQLlite Db storage, password grant options initial login is taking up to 20s. When I look at the logs I see a bunch of SQL access at first login with few seconds gap between each. SQL access it self is only 2-3 ms. It looks like the overhead is in opening and closing the connection. Is there a way Entity Framework can be set to persist connections for Configuration Store Db context?

Comment: does spinning up and opening just a regular SqlLite connection to the same server still have this behavior?

Comment: I connect with sqllite browser and I don't see any delays.  See my logs below. This cycle of opening, executing, closing and then again opening, executing is repeated multiple times.

Comment: Sorry couldn't post logs due to length limitation. But you get the idea

Comment: Post your connection string, opening and closing of DB connections should not be an issue. Is connection pooling enabled?

Comment: connection string is just db name and password.